# Xackup Backup Type for Xen Server 6.5

Tags: backup, memory, xen, xenserver, disk-image

I'm running the **Xackup** trial and started backing up a few linux and windows VM's. I selected **disk and memory state** as the type of backup. Everything ran fine and backed up ok.

When I went to edit the scheduled backup plan I made to add another VM it complains that "**a VM saved to a storage location cannot be restored to its previous running state and can have a greater performance impact on a system while a snapshot is taken.**"

Can anybody confirm whether or not this is 100% true? I am able to still select the option for **disk and memory** and the backups run fine. I can **restore** as well without issue. My only issue is I'm still testing out xen and xackups so I haven't been able to test out backups on important machines. So naturally I'm a little hesitant to commit to this.

If somebody could shed some light on disk backups vs. memory + disk backups I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a "disk backup" is a snapshot of just the disk: Imagine shutting down a computer and backing up the disk. The RAM is empty becaus ethe computer is shutdown, so all the files are closed and whatnot.

Now a "disk + memory backup" is like backing up the disk and the exact state of the RAM at the same time, while the computer is running: Some files are open in RAM and contents not yet written to disk.

So I imagine that if you having success with "disk and memory state" backups, its because you don't realize that you are actually only getting the contents of the disk in the backup, and not the contents of the RAM.